# How to create a dataframe with a custom name

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to know how to assign a different name to each dataframe with a for loop. 
Below I read all the data frames and decide the names, I have two dataframes for each country.

```
years = ['2015', '2016'] 
nations = ['ITA', 'SPA']
path_list = []
name_list = []
for year in years:
    for nation in nations:
        path_list.append('D://Desktop//mydata//'+year+'//'+nation+'.csv')
    for path in path_list:
        data = pd.read_csv(percorso, usecols=['Date', 'Name'])
        name_df = ('df_' + path[-12:-8] + '_' + path[-6:-4]) 
        name_list.append(name_df)
```

From this script I get a list containing all the names I want to assign to the corresponding 4 data frames:

```
name_list = ['df_2015_I1', 'df_2015_I2', 'df_2016_I1', 'df_2016_I2']
```

Now we come to the problem, I try to assign the name to the dataframe but when I try to refer to the dataframe with the new name outside the loop I can't find it

```
df = {}
for name in name_list:
    df[name] = pd.DataFrame()
    df[name] = df[name].append(data, ignore_index=True)


print(df_2015_I1) #ERROR NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```py
df = {}
for name in name_list:
    df[name] = pd.DataFrame(data, ignore_index=True)

print(df['df_2015_I1'])
```

I think your original code would work if you added print(df['df_2015_I1']), remember you are storing each of these dataframes in a dictionary to then reference them by name.

Comment: always gives me the same error, NameError: name 'df_2015_I1' is not defined

Comment: can you try again now

Comment: unfortunately I have the same mistake, let's try to think in another way. I have two lists one of the names for the data frames and a list for the file path. 
                                                                                                                 
     NAMES = ['df_2015_I1', 'df_2015_I2', 'df_2016_I1', 'df_2016_I2']             
                                                               
   and PATH=['D://Desktop//2015//I1.csv', 'D://Desktop//2015//I2.csv', 'D://Desktop//2016//I1.csv', 'D://Desktop//2016//I2.csv']

Comment: Sorry my cloudy mind yesterday, please see above I forgot to put strings around the dictionary key. Otherwise it is trying to look for the variable df_2015_I1 to use as the key, rather than using 'df_2015_I1' as the key.